# Whenever I tries to add js function in my function.php file in wordpress it gives me fata memory error

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I tries to add  `wp_enqueue_scripts('main-university-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '2.O', true);`  in my `function.php` file. It gives me a fatal memory error. I am using local host xamp.

Comment: Please show us your code and your attempts.

Comment: <?php 
function university_files() { 
 wp_enqueue_scripts('main-university-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '2.0', true); 
 wp_enqueue_style("custom-google-fonts", '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,400i,700,700i');
 wp_enqueue_style('font_awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'university_files');

Comment: Hi Aleem. Might want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. These will increase your chances of getting a good answer. Better to include code in question, not in the comments.